# Word 2013 does not "open" a file instead downloads the index page and ignores the session

Tags: javascript, php, linux, apache, internet-explorer

So I am using a LAMP stack server running the VTiger CRM application and for some reason when I download a word file (.doc or .docx file) and click "open" with word 2013 with internet explorer 10/11 on a windows 8 machine the download fails.

It works fine in Chrome or Firefox and works using a different editor (i.e. Libre office) so I find this issue very odd.

[investigating w/ dev tools](http://devl04.borugroup.com/eugene_scray/escray/pictures/6-18-2014%2011-35-42%20AM.png)

[Final state w/ dev tools](http://devl04.borugroup.com/eugene_scray/escray/pictures/6-18-2014%2011-37-17%20AM.png)

Ive tried the following:

- Running all current updates
- Disabling all security settings on MSIE.
- Disabling Protected View on Word 2013
- Running MSIE in 7,8,9, and 10 w/ compatibility mode
- Disabling Cache on the server
- Setting Session Timeout Registries to a large value (I thought for some reason the 
  session refresh was being intercepted by my application)

Any ideas on something else I can try?